# Make Google map span long pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a very long webpage, i.e. the user needs to scroll down the page to see all the information that is there.

I am using google maps as the background for the page. However, the Google map is only filling the first page of the website. As soon as I scroll down, the map is not there anymore and it is only filling 100% of the initial view.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697805/how-do-i-make-a-google-map-span-100-remaining-height-between-header-and-footer) which suggests that Google map does not know 100% of what to span, hence one should explicitly mention height:100% in body so that when height:100% is mentioned in the div containing Google maps, it knows that it has to span the entire body of the web page.

I have tried the above solution, but it is not solving my problem. How do I get Google maps to span across a very long webpage?

The basic set up is like this:

```
<body>
<div id="main-content">  <!--The main data is held here. This is the forefround-->
        This in turn contains several divs and the main information
</div>
<div id="map-canvas">

</div>
</body>
```

The css is as follows:

```
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; /*changing this to fixed makes the map dissapear*/
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  z-index: 0;
}

#main-content {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

html, p, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;                
    height: 100%;
}
```

As suggested in one of the answers, it would be nice if the map background remains constant while the rest of the page is scrollable.

Comment: Can you post a link to an example or show your code? Without seeing your set up it is pretty hard to help.

Comment: Yep, can we see some code please.

Comment: I have added some code. But I am avoiding putting too much as it may be difficult to go through it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting a fixed position on the map-container.
I came across this Fiddle on the web:

http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/927/

```
#map-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

It will stick the map to the page on window size.
Any other content can remain scrollable.

Comment: I was using position: absolute. Changing it to fixed stops the map from displaying. But I like your solution. It would be nice if the map stays fixed while other content is scrollable.

Comment: Well if you want to use it as a background, then that seems to me to be the most logical solution. If the map doesn't display anymore, then check width/height and Z-index. It should definitely show up.

Comment: I have checked those. Still no improvement :(

Comment: Check the element inspector in Google Chrome and hover the #map-container to check its dimensions. As you see in the JSFiddle, it should work. Create your own JSFiddle and reproduce the problem that you have. Or even better; adapt your code to the code in the JSFiddle - why fix what is not broken?